# get certain amount of records of multiple values

Tags: sqlite, limit-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
_id,  name,  type
1     A_0    a
2     A_1    a
3     A_2    a
4     A_3    a
5     B_0    b
6     B_1    b
7     B_2    b
8     B_3    b
```

I'd like to get a search result where I get exactly 2 rows of each type.

Update:

I result should look like this:
(there will be many more types)

```
_id,  name,  type
1     A_0    a
2     A_1    a
5     B_0    b
6     B_1    b
```

Does anyone happen to have a solution on this?

Comment: Please post desired result for sample data.

Comment: What criteria determine which two you want?

Comment: the first 2 results of each type would be good.

Answer (score 0):

For each type get 2 rows ordered by _id then pull of the rows with those ids in an outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM TheTable AS X WHERE _id IN 
(
      SELECT Y._id FROM TheTable AS Y
      WHERE X.type = Y.type
      ORDER BY Y._id ASC
      LIMIT 2
) ORDER BY _id;
```

Comment: This seems to take hours...after 10 min still loading. I have a database with 200k+ entries.

Comment: Is there an index on _id? - There is a different JOIN approach here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119900/efficient-way-to-get-last-10-rows-of-each-group-in-sqlite-can-cte-help

Comment: Yes, there is. Could you please write some code for this example here?